# Trouble Finding ID's with Duplicate Fields

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

My data looks like this:

```
ID  Email
1   someone@hotmail.com
2   someone1@hotmail.com
3   someone2@hotmail.com
4   someone3@hotmail.com
5   someone4@hotmail.com
6   someone5@hotmail.com
```

There should be exactly 1 email per ID, but there's not.

```
> dim(data)
[1] 5071    2
> length(unique(data$Person_Onyx_Id))
[1] 5071
> length((data$Email))
[1] 5071
> length(unique(data$Email))
[1] 4481
```

So, I need to find the ID's with duplicated email addresses.

Seems like this should be easy, but I'm striking out:

```
> sqldf("select ID, count(Email) from data  group by ID having count(Email) > 1")
[1] ID count(Email)  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I've also tried taking off the `having` clause and sending the result to an object and sorting the object by the `count(Email)`... it appears that every `ID` has `count(Email)` of 1...

I would `dput` the actual data but I can't due to the sensitivity of email addresses.

Comment: look at `?duplicated`

Comment: Try `Group By Emails` then look for IDs where Emails counts more than 1. 

If you Group By ID you will always get 1 as Count(Email)

Comment: @shadow `duplicated` gave `logical(0)` Idk why, because there are definitely duplicates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you also sure you don't have the opposite condition, multiple ids with the same email?

```
select Email, count(*)
from data
group by Email
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have `NULL` emails.  You could find this by using `count(*)` rather than `count(email)`:

```
select ID, count(*)
from data
group by ID
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was also suspicious of this but that gives me `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` as well...

Comment: OK I have had a look at the duplicates via View(datat$Email[order(data$Email),]) so they were duplicates afterall